# How to use audio convert with terminal parameter?

Tags: terminal, media, flac, aac

I want to convert a set of `flac` files to `aac` using best resolution for `aac` file .

I found this tool [audio convert](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/audio-convert) but I am missing the man page or a help side. The command works when I use

```
audio-convert <filename>.flac
```

but it starts some graphical choice wizard. Is there a way to only use one terminal command so I can batch it over a set files?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not the best tool to do the conversion from the command-line, it is not designed to be used this way.

This tool depends on zenity(which shows the graphical part) and processes files one-by-one, this is an excerpt from the README file provided by the tool

> to use it as a plain bash script, provided you have access to an x session and have zenity installed, simply type: path/to/audio-convert path/to/filename... and specify as many filenames as you want. they will be processed one by one, just as it happens when you select multiple files on nautilus or rox.

I would suggest that you use the tools used by the script you mentioned, which is `faac` for AAC encoding, but you will have to decode FLAC files first, using `flac`.

For details about calling `faac` and `flac` from the terminal, you can look up online documentation, you will find many examples as they are commonly used, and you can also check the functions aac_encode() and flac_decode() in the script `audio-convert`:

```bsh
flac_decode ()
{
    temp_file=`echo "$1" | sed 's/\.\w*$/'.wav'/'`
    flac -d "$1" -o "$temp_file" 2>&1 | awk -vRS='\r' -F':' '!/done/{gsub(/ /,"");gsub(/% complete/,"");if(NR>1)print $2; fflush();}' | zenity --progress --title="$title" --text="$2 $1" --auto-close
}
```

and

```bsh
aac_encode ()
{
    if [ $fields -eq 0 ] || [ $pass_metatags -eq 0 ]
        then
                aac_parse_fields
        faac -w "${aac_fields[@]}" -q $quality -o "$3" "$2" 2>&1 | awk -vRS='\r' '(NR>1){gsub(/%/," ");print $3; fflush();}' | zenity --progress --title="$title" --text="$conversion $1" --auto-close
    else
        faac -q $quality -o "$3" "$2" 2>&1 | awk -vRS='\r' '(NR>1){gsub(/%/," ");print $3; fflush();}' | zenity --progress --title="$title" --text="$conversion $1" --auto-close
    fi
}
```

but keep in mind you can't use them as is from `audio-convert` because they depend on other variables defined in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you have a specific command to convert flac to aac with `faac`

Comment: The commands are faac and flac, I added a bit more info in the comment.